# changing current directory from a child process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I wrote a script that changes current directory.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd userA/toWhere/
```

When the script is sourced, it changes the current directory but I want to change it from child process by using `bash invocation`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No,

```
bash scriptname
```

opens a subshell and any directory changes within that subshell do not affect the calling shell. Sourcing is the only option.

Comment: can we arrange for a shell script to be executed in a child process and still change the current directory? @Thomas Kühn

Comment: @Ms.Sahin: Now I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking. Do you mean to run call a script from the terminal, which uses another script to change the terminal? Where would you want to see the directory change? Could you maybe add some pseudo-code to your question to show the minimal workflow and explain what the final result should be?